# Looping over dates in datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset that looks as follows -  the actual thing is much larger (>300K rows), but this should do.

```
    datetime                type    price   bid?    quantity    order book
0   2017-03-01 09:30:00.656 quote   6.15    T       800000.0    2493
1   2017-03-01 09:30:00.656 quote   6.20    T       800000.0    2493
2   2017-03-03 09:30:00.657 quote   6.25    F       800000.0    2493
3   2017-03-04 09:30:00.669 quote   6.15    T       2600000.0   2493
4   2017-03-10 09:30:00.669 quote   6.30    F       800000.0    2493
5   2017-03-28 09:30:00.669 quote   6.35    F       800000.0    2493
6   2017-03-28 09:30:00.682 quote   6.25    F       1200000.0   2493
7   2017-03-30 09:30:00.684 quote   6.20    T       2300000.0   2493
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to loop a function over all the dates in the dataset. More specifically, I am trying to run my analysis on a daily basis. What I have tried so far is:

```
for date in y['datetime'].dt.date():
print(date)
```

And:

```
y.groupby(columns=y['datetime'].dt.date())
```

but both methods result in

```
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need `y['datetime'].dt.date`. `date` is an attribute.

Comment: `df[['datetime']].info()`.  What is its type?

Comment: @Alexander datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need loop in daily basis by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) function `f`:

```
def f(x):
    #sample function
    print (x)
    x['price'] = x['price'] * 2 + x['quantity']
    ... 
    return x

df = y.groupby(y['datetime'].dt.date).apply(f)
print (df)
```

Or use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) - it create consecutive `DatetimeIndex`, but if some dates are missing, add `NaN`s:

```
y.resample('D', on='datetime').apply(f)
```

Comment: Yes I think that's exactly what I'm looking for! Any idea regarding the speed of both methods?

Comment: I think first is faster. But mainly it depends of function - if possible the best is use pandas high optimalize functions and methods.

Comment: So if possible can you describe your function?

Answer (score 0):

Well, **don't loop**.

If you have 300k rows, then loops will be very slow and suboptimal.

Here is an alternative solution :

A common practice in using a time series data is to use the timestamp as the row index.

To do so, you can:
`y = y.set_index('datetime)`

Afterwards, if you would like to get the dates, you can simply :
`dates = y.index.date`

Comment: Yes, I agree, the best is not loop. But sometimes it is only way for process data, if all another methods failed. So it depends of function of OP.